# How to install Laravel Vite?

Tags: laravel, npm, vite, npx

The [Laravel Vite Doc](https://laravel-vite.innocenzi.dev/guide/#vanilla) sais to run:

```
npx apply laravel:vite --ignore-existing
```

inside your project root to install `vite` in your `laravel project`.

When I try to do that in a freshly installed laravel project it shows this:

```
zsh:1: command not found: laravel:vite
```

What am I doing wrong?

Using `Macos Big Sur` with `PhpStorm`.

Comment: I can't reproduce that error (also on Big Sur). How did you run that command?

Comment: Hey, thanks for looking into this. I just typed it into the PhpStorm terminal inside my project root directory after creating a laravel/laravel composer project

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That command no longer applies to newly created projects (as of `laravel-vite` [0.1.27](https://github.com/innocenzi/laravel-vite/releases/tag/0.1.27), released a few days ago), and it now results in a different error:

```sh
$ npx apply laravel:vite --ignore-existing
[ info ]  Applying preset laravel:vite.
[ error ]  The preset could not be evaluated.
evalmachine.<anonymous>:13
var preset_default = definePreset({
                     ^

ReferenceError: definePreset is not defined
    at evalmachine.<anonymous>:13:22
    at Script.runInContext (node:vm:139:12)
    at Object.runInContext (node:vm:289:6)
    at ModuleImporter.evaluateConfiguration (/Users/tony/src/laravel-vite-demo/example-app/node_modules/apply/dist/Importer/ModuleImporter.js:68:26)
    at ModuleImporter.import (/Users/tony/src/laravel-vite-demo/example-app/node_modules/apply/dist/Importer/ModuleImporter.js:17:27)
    at PresetApplier.run (/Users/tony/src/laravel-vite-demo/example-app/node_modules/apply/dist/Applier/PresetApplier.js:22:87)
    at async CommandLineInterface.apply (/Users/tony/src/laravel-vite-demo/example-app/node_modules/apply/dist/IO/CommandLineInterface.js:57:16)
    at async CommandLineInterface.run (/Users/tony/src/laravel-vite-demo/example-app/node_modules/apply/dist/IO/CommandLineInterface.js:54:16)
```

However, the command shown in the [`laravel-presets/vite` repository](https://github.com/laravel-presets/vite/blob/8c2ad8c/README.md) (the source repo for the `laravel:vite` preset) worked for me -- i.e., it augmented the Laravel project with Vite:

```sh
# Run this command from root of Laravel project
npx @preset/cli apply --debug laravel:vite
```

`@preset/cli` currently suppresses all output (including errors), so the `--debug` flag above is important. Since the verbose log is difficult to follow, I recommend redirecting the output to a file, and searching it for the word `exception`.

### Tips

- To ensure the preset succeeds, you must have [`php@8.0`](https://www.php.net/releases/8.0/en.php) (e.g., from [Homebrew](https://brew.sh/)) and [`composer`](https://getcomposer.org/) installed and available from the command line. Add the paths to those binaries to your `PATH` environment variable.
- The Vite server must be started separately from the PHP server. Run `npm run dev` in one terminal; and `php artisan serve` from another.

Answer (score 1):

Vite is now the default frontend asset bundler in laravel which replaces webpack. No additional installations are needed for new projects.

https://laravel-news.com/vite-is-the-default-frontend-asset-bundler-for-laravel-applications